# Textfield Delegate functions not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm working on an app where there are multiple steps to go in a flow. I transformed the return key on all `UItextfields`into a "next" button, and I hooked up the delegates like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.input.delegate = self
    setupRX()
}
```

I also implemented the following delegate method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("did")
    if self.nextButton.isEnabled {
        print("did")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextStep", sender: nil)
    }

    return true
}
```

However the above function never gets called... As far as I know, I check all the boxes; I set the delegate, I implemented `UITextFieldDelegate` and I made the method like it's supposed to be made.

Did I miss something or is this perhaps a bug?

Comment: did you set `:UITextFieldDelegate`? in your viewController declaration?

Comment: @ReinierMelian "I implemented UITextFieldDelegate"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with underscore before textField

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("did")
    if self.nextButton.isEnabled {
        print("did")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextStep", sender: nil)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Wow, such a small detail... Completely missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with Wesley. Works on Swift 5, in a UIView. Thanks !